# jQuery minicolor.js not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm currently implementing jQuery [minicolor.js](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/) in an input box in my website, as you can [see by clicking here](http://alexanderlozada.com/themer/?pSize=a).  Going by the documents listed above, I seem to have done everything correctly, yet I'm still having a problem.

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.color').each(function(){
        $(this).minicolors();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="color">
</form>
```

I've also properly included jQuery, minicolor.js, and the css file.  Yet, for some reason it ends up looking like this.

[image]

It works, but the graphics for it are all messed up - which I *think* would be related to the CSS file, but I'm positive I linked it correctly.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the `jquery.minicolors.png` file is not loaded (it's not in your `themer` folder).

Just download it here: https://raw.github.com/claviska/jquery-minicolors/master/jquery.minicolors.png

Comment: That did the trick.  Odd, maybe I'm overlooking it, but I didn't see any mention of including that file in the page I linked.  I should have checked the full github repo, though.  Thanks for catching my error.